# how to save the resume to blob in php?

Tags: php, blob

i cant find what's wrong with the coding, here is my coding:

```
daftar( cucidata( $_POST["username"]), 
        cucidata($_POST["password1"]),
        cucidata($_POST["password2"]),
        cucidata($_POST["name"]),
        cucidata($_POST["email"]),
        $_FILES["photo"]["name"],
        $con,
        $_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"],
        cucidata($_POST["dob"]),
        cucidata($_POST["gender"]),
        cucidata($_POST["hp"]),
        cucidata($_POST["address"]),
        cucidata($_POST["university"]),
        cucidata($_POST["gd"]),
        cucidata($_POST["qualitification"]),
        cucidata($_POST["fos"]),
        cucidata($_POST["mos"]),
        cucidata($_POST["ai"]),
        cucidata($_POST["jt"]),
        cucidata($_POST["cn"]),
        cucidata($_POST["pe1"]),
        cucidata($_POST["pe2"]),
        ($_FILES["resume"]["name"]),
        $con,
        $_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"]
);

//save the resume to blob
$resumeFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($resume,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); //dapatkan jenis resume
$resumeData =addslashes(file_get_contents($resumeFileType));
$resumeProperties = getimageSize($resumeFileType);


mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tbl_user 
                (username,pwd,name,email,picture,pictype,
                dob,gender,hp,address,university,gd,
                qualitification,fos,mos,ai,jt,cn,pe1,pe2,
                resume,resumetype) 
        values ('$user','$pwd','$name','$email','{$imgData}',
                '{$imageProperties['mime']}','$dob','$gender',
                '$hp','$address','$university','$gd',
                '$qualitification','$fos','$mos','$ai',
                '$jt','$cn','$pe1','$pe2','{$resumeData}',
                '{$resumeProperties['mime']})") 
        or die (mysqli_error($con));
```

this is the result:

> Warning: file_get_contents(pdf): failed to open stream: No such file
> or directory in C:\laragon\www\intern\include\main_function.php on
> line 38
>
> Warning: getimagesize(pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or
> directory in C:\laragon\www\intern\include\main_function.php on line
> 39
>
> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in
> C:\laragon\www\intern\include\main_function.php on line 42 You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '')' at line 1

could someone enlighten me regarding this issue?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Also, be warned that the given `INSERT`  query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"]` instead of the file extension for `file_get_contents()`. Also, don't use `getimagesize()` as resumes are generally not images. You can get the MIME type with the `finfo_open()` and `finfo_file()` functions. Try updating your code to read the resume file contents using the temporary path and keep the MIME type.

Also, try using a beautifier before posting code as it makes it easier to read. Here's one I found for PHP: https://codebeautify.org/php-beautifier.